# codeigniter post html textarea

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, post, textarea

when i try to post html from my textarea the variable value is empty and form_validation show error message that the input is required......

i search for solution and i didn't found ....

this is my code

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('send_message/validate'); ?>">

                    <?php

                    echo validation_errors();

                    echo form_dropdown('cat_name', $plan_cat);
                    ?>
                    <div>
                            <span><label>اسم الراسل باللغه الانجليزية</label></span>
                            <span><input name="from" type="text" class="textbox" value="<?php echo set_value('from'); ?>" /></span>
                        </div>
                    <div>
                            <span><label>العنوان</label></span>
                            <span><input name="subject" type="text" class="textbox" value="<?php echo set_value('subject'); ?>" /></span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span><label>الرساله</label></span>


                            <?php
                                /*
                                $options = array(
                                'name' => 'message',
                                'id' => 'elm1'
                                );

                                echo form_textarea($options);
                            */
                            ?>

                            <textarea name="message" id="elm1"><?php echo set_value('message'); ?></textarea>

                        </div>

                    <div>
                            <span><input type="submit" value="ارسل" /></span>
                      </div>


                    <?php

                echo form_close();


                ?>
```

and this is my controller code :

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('from', 'الراسل', 'required|min_length[8]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject', 'عنوان الرساله', 'required|min_length[6]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'الرساله', 'trim|required|min_length[10]|xss_clean');


        if($this->form_validation->run() == false){


            $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

            $send = array(
            'title' => 'ارسل الرساله',
            'plan' => $this->user_plan->get_plan($user_id)
            );

            $this->load->library('parser');
            $this->parser->parse('header', $send);
            $this->parser->parse('send_message', $send);
            $this->parser->parse('footer', $send);


        }else{

            $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
            $plan_cat = $this->input->post('cat_name');
            $from = $this->input->post('from', true);
            $subject = $this->input->post('subject', true);
            $message = $this->input->post('message', true);

            $message = '<code>'.$message.'</code>';
```

i hope to find way to solve this :)

Answer (score 0):

First , before going deep in your code , I have to say that : using base_url functionality as action attribute is bad. You have to use site_url instead in this way :

```
echo site_url('send_message/validate');
```

The reason stands behind that :

- **site_url** gives you the full URL including the main processing file (index.php) which is important to handle your MVC requests (e.g http://domain.com/codeigniter/index.php/send_message/validate)
- **base_ur** gives you the URL without any consideration for the main file (index.php) (e.g http://domain.com/codeigniter/send_message/validate)

Second (And the important). I see that you are using XSS Filter for the (message) which means you are trying to put illegal content in the textarea. Try to put anything else everything will be ok.

So , make sure that your message value doesn't contain illegal characters.

Comment: Try to submit all fields , do you see the submitted values on the fields ?

Comment: Could you please tell me , what is the value you try to put on message textarea ?

Comment: i guess html code stop some queries because it works fine if the value not html

Comment: this is the source code

<div style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial,sans-serif;">
<div style="text-align: center;"><strong><u><font size="6">مفأجات شركة اللبق لأول مرة فى دول الخليج</font></u></strong></div>
</div>
<div class="ecxgmail_quote" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">
<div dir="rtl">
<div dir="rtl">

Comment: Review the second part of my answer , i did some changes !

Comment: thanks my brother for your effort,, but it isn't works fine all the time,,, i want to ask you ,, which way can i do to solve html code problem after post the value or store in variable ??